# What is Server resource quota?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

In SharePoint admin center (Office 365) my site collections may be assigned storage quota and server resource quota. [Here is even MSDN article explainig how to change it](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/change-site-collection-storage-and-server-resource-quotas-HA102772729.aspx#_Toc341785493). By default, resource quota is 300.

What do those numbers mean? What is quota of 300?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my understanding, Microsoft is using the "resources" word purposefully to be vague. It is a vague reference to memory and CPU time. My guess is that microsoft didn't want to make any promises when it comes to CPU or memory, so we get "resources". Smart, and fairly humorous.

So, to answer your question, "resources" is the maximum amount of relative CPU and memory allocated to a site collection and or site collection group.

The actual CPU in MHertz and memory in MBs is unknown.

Answer (score 6):

Office 365 sites run in the cloud, there is not a limit on CPU usage as previously described, but these instances are shared.  To prevent degradation of performance and services, these quotas are put in place to help with isolation.  An organization is provided with a quantity of resources to split between site collections based on the number of users in the organization.  You should allocate a larger quota to sites where there is heavier usage, planned code deployments, heavy app consumption, or heavy collaboration.  The usage can also be measured over time to allocate appropriate resources.  Your software vendor, LAR, partners or Microsoft can also help with sizing if you run into problems.